# How to stop users from visiting staging area after production deployment

Tags: deployment, lifecycle, staging

We have a few servers that have different roles. For instance, we have production servers, and testing/staging servers. We have a few end users who forget to switch paths to production once things are tested and approved or use; They use the new paths for a bit, then revert back to using the testing/staging at some point for some reason that we can't understand other than stupidity. We still want to be able to get a glimpse into our staging environment after pushing a build into production, but we want to stop them from being able to still hit those servers/services.

We are now pondering some solutions to this problem. One being never give them the direct staging url.  An idea would be to create a virtual directory or have a set of domain aliases that we could give them and then shut down while still allowing us access to these endpoints. We could restrict our main staging domain to the office ip range so they never have direct access and call it good.

Does this sound like a good solution? Is our process wrong, are there better routes?

I am interested in solutions for websites as well as web services where visuals can't be used effectively.

Comment: how do you think you can stop people from being stupid?

Comment: @phoet we can't stop people from being stupid, but we can remind them with a 404 page or something right?

Answer (score 0):

We've run into this at my work as well… quite recently in fact.  One thing that I thought about other than the virtual directory was setting up specific ports for them to test on then either take the ports down or change them for our internal uses only.

Comment: or change virtual hosts like staging1 staging2 ... staging69 after each release

Answer (score 0):

Well without details in how your application is deployed it could be troublesome to give concrete examples.  One wonderful solution is to get better users :P  Perhaps a more possible solution however is to let your production boxes move a certain set of users(as decided in your code) to your test/staging systems.  I.E. the User always connects to Production, but the production machines at connect/auth time, may decide these people are too cool for production let them run the test/staging code instead.

It's not a fullproof method of course, but it works for many many websites to let a certain set of users into different parts of their codebase.

I don't know how feasible this would be for you, but it's a possibility perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I find that users sometimes have difficulties with URLs, and don't like to have subtle changes like port number in the address.

The best approach I've found is to have the application tell the user what environment they are in.

For example, my teams have used absolutely positioned headers or footers, color coded for Dev/Staging environments that show the application version number with an alpha/beta tag, along with a message that says "Work done on this site will be lost, use Production (link) to keep your work." Typically we make the Dev area red, and the staging area yellow. We also like to put a link to the bug tracking system right in this area.

On production there is not usually a region like this. However, we do sometimes provide positive reinforcement by placing a green region, with the app version and a Production tag in it, and then fade the green region away after a few seconds. This helps keep the app front and center, but let's the user know they are in the right place.

Comment: how about if you had a web api or some sort of SOA where there is no GUI really?

Comment: Interesting, is your scenario that you have your end users entering API URI's in application config?

Comment: I'm not sure how they are consuming it. But yes something along those lines most likely.

Comment: If they are using the service through a client you control, then you can still provide visual feedback in the client application as described above. If you don't own the client, perhaps you can alter the data the service returns in some way to make it apparent

Comment: nope we just provide the service, they handle the client stuff.